# .net core - FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created an ASP.NET Core Web Application(.Net Core)

I have used following to import my existing dlls using single NuGet package.

```
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "net451",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

},

All my dlls are built up on .net framework 4.0. and one of the dlls references System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll(4.0.0.0)

When I run the project I am getting FileNotFoundException.

Following is an error message-

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think the versions are compatible - you may need to specify later versions (4.3.0). Did you specify dependencies in the project.json file?